# HTTPS Site- Safari could not open the page because the server has stopped responding

Tags: ios, http, iis, https, safari

I have a site hosted a application with HTTPS. Now this works perfectly on android devices. But same site is not opening in IOS device with safari browser. It give me an error as  Safari could not open the page because the server has stopped responding.
Do i need to do some sort of configuration for this?

Answer (score 0):

**It did happen to me as well!** Drove me nuts!

Give this a try:

**Go to Settings → scroll down to Safari → in Safari settings, Select both Clear History and Clear Cookies and Data.**

Let me know if it does the trick...

You have a sweet day!